# install ubuntu and windows 7 on separate ssds

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

i have one 500 Gb ssd and one 128 Gb ssd
windows 7 is installed on first one and I want to install ubuntu on second one
im kind of new in this kind of things so i dont know much about bootloader and other things
i have searched alot but im more confused know
my question is how to install ubuntu on second ssd without loosing windows on first ssd and of course be able on startup to choose between ubuntu and win7
my win7 is installed in bios legacy mode
i really need help
sorry for my english
tnx

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS only? You realize Windows 7 is EoL or End of Life and should not be used to access Internet. If system is UEFI or if SSD may be moved to a newer UEFI system in near future, better to partition in gpt mode and add both an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 300MB to 500MB) and a bios_grub (unformatted 1MB), with bios_grub flag. But to dual boot you have to install in BIOS mode and select Ubuntu drive for grub boot loader using Something Else. Make / (root) as ext4 & 30GB or so & rest as /home. ESP will not be used, until you convert to UEFI boot, & saves doing entire drive.

Answer (score 0):

### Dual Boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10 on Separate SSD's

- Confirm if Windows boots in BIOS mode or UEFI mode: In Run, type `msinfo32System`, In Summary under System Information, see if the BIOS Mode item has a value of Legacy or UEFI.
- Unplug the Windows SSD before installing Ubuntu.
- Boot Ubuntu, install USB in same BIOS/UEFI mode as Windows.
- Install Ubuntu.
- Plug in Windows SSD.
- Set Ubuntu HDD as first hard drive.
- Boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` this will add Windows to Ubuntu's bootloader menu.

This method will preserve the bootloader on the Windows SSD in case the Ubuntu SSD is ever moved or replaced.